# no match for operator= using a std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, constants

I've got a class declared like this:

```
class Level
{
    private:
        std::vector<mapObject::MapObject> features;
    (...)
};
```

and in one of its member functions I try to iterate through that vector like this:

```
vector<mapObject::MapObject::iterator it;
for(it=features.begin(); it<features.end(); it++)
{
    /* loop code */
}
```

This seems straightforward to me, but g++ gives me this error:

``` src/Level.cpp:402: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘it = ((const yarl::level::Level*)this)->yarl::level::Level::features.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = yarl::mapObject::MapObject, _Alloc = std::allocator<yarl::mapObject::MapObject>]()’

/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator.h:669: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<yarl::mapObject::MapObject*,std::vector > >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<yarl::mapObject::MapObject*,std::vector > >::operator=(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<yarl::mapObject::MapObject*, ``std::vector<yarl::mapObject::MapObject, std::allocator<yarl::mapObject::MapObject> > >&) ```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You mean `vector<mapObject::MapObject>::iterator it;`? You missed an angle bracket here.

Comment: C++'s error messages look like vomit mixed with more vomit and placed neatly within angle brackets.

Comment: @Aviral:  I don't use g++ on a regular basis, but other compilers (namely Visual C++ and Intel C++, which uses the EDG frontend) have template error messages that are _much_ easier to read than that, IMO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd guess that this part of the error describes your problem:

```
(const yarl::level::Level*)this
```

Is the member function in which this code is found a const-qualified member function?  If so, you'll need to use a `const_iterator`:

```
vector<mapObject::MapObject>::const_iterator it;
```

If the member function is const-qualified, then only the const-qualified overloads of `begin()` and `end()` on the member vector will be available, and both of those return `const_iterator`s.

Comment: This was the problem.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Did you close your right-angle bracket here?

```
vector<mapObject::MapObject::iterator it;
```

If you want a vector of objects, your object needs an operator=. Does MapObject have one? If not, consider a vector of pointers to MapObject.

Comment: The error comes from assigning the iterator, not assigning an object in the vector. You might get this error if the invalid line were actually `vector<MapObject::iterator> it;`, which is valid but wrong. It should be `vector<MapObject>::iterator it;`.

Comment: Note that unless you explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, the compiler will provide one for you, so even if you don't see one in the class definition, it still has one.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would check to see that the mapObject::MapObject has a default constructor and a public assignment operator.

Somewhere in the class header, you should see something like:

```
public:
    MapObject();
    operator=(const MapObject &mapObject);
```

Which means that the class has a default constructor and an assignment operator.

A std::vector cannot be instantiated using a class without a default constructor, and you cannot iterate through the class as above without an assignment operator.

So, add an assignment operator to your class definition and your iteration will compile.

Comment: `std::vector` _can_ be instantiated for a type without a default constructor, you just lose a bit of the functionality (e.g., when you resize the vector, you have to provide an object to copy into the new slots).

Answer (score 0):

@James McNellis's answer (the "green checked" best answer) fixed my error with a similar description, however my error was caused by what @tmarthal mentioned his answer post (not defining an assignment operator).  His suggested fix is to include an assignment operator but I just wanted to add that I was also able fix this error by using std::vector<>::const_iterator instead of std::vector<>::iterator for classes where no assignment operator is defined.  I'm not sure whether this truly a correct fix or just something that kept the compiler from complaining however.